# Why can't I drag images?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am working off of http://www.raywenderlich.com/33806/how-to-make-a-letterword-game-with-uikit-part-2 , and it says in reference to the view to add the following to the implementation:

```
int _xOffset, _yOffset;
```

For the initializer:

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

It also gives three methods to implement to handle dragging:

```
#pragma mark - dragging the tile
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
    _xOffset = pt.x - self.center.x;
    _yOffset = pt.y - self.center.y;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
    self.center = CGPointMake(pt.x - _xOffset, pt.y - _yOffset);
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Nothing seems to happen, though, when I touch one of the images and try to drag it around. It seems to never move.

There is more work than this to do; I want to do something specific based on where a dragged image is dropped. But right now I'm working on the smoke test, and I cannot see any change in the UI behavior from before when I added this code.

Thanks for any help,

Comment: Did you check if these methods are called or not when you try to drag an imageview?

Comment: I don't think why you using self.center? You need to try with image... self.imageView.center.

Comment: self.center has worked so far.

Comment: where are you placing this code in your project? i would just make sure this code is in your imageview subclass and not in your view controller. also make sure you have changed the class type to your custom class for your imageview in the identity inspector in ib.